# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (200, 200, 3) but got array with shape (200, 200, 4)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

everybody. I'm using Keras for image classification. I have images (200,200,4) that have 4 layers (Result of the fusion of rgb plus the distance map).

```
`import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.applications import resnet50
from keras.regularizers import l2
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
import tensorflow as tf
import keras

os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID" # read gpu in pci order, just like nvidia-smi
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="3" # select a number

# Etape 1: Initialisation du cnn
classifier = Sequential()
# Etape de convolution. Ajouter la couche de convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, strides=1, 
                             input_shape=(200, 200, 4), activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Ajout d'une couche de convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Ajout d'une couche de convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Ajout d'une couche de convolution
classifier.add(Convolution2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
# Etape de flatening
classifier.add(Flatten())
# Etape 4 Couche completement connectée
classifier.add(Dense(units=2048, activation="relu", kernel_regularizer=l2(0.01), bias_regularizer=l2(0.01)))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))

classifier.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))
# Compilation du reseau
from keras.optimizers import Adam
opt = Adam(lr=0.0009)
classifier.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="binary_crossentropy",
                   metrics=["accuracy"])

# checkpoint
filepath = "classification_4channels.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        brightness_range=(0.1, 0.9),
        channel_shift_range=150.0,
        horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)


training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'datasetTe/training_set',
        target_size=(200, 200),
        color_mode='rgba',
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')


test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'datasetTe/test_set',
        target_size=(200, 200),
        color_mode='rgba',
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

history = classifier.fit_generator(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=(training_set.samples / 32),
        epochs=20,
        callbacks=callbacks_list,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=(test_set.samples / 32)

        )
```

`
But when I execute the code, it gives me this error.

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have shape (200, 200, 3) but got array with shape (200, 200, 4).

I'm new to deeplearning. Please help me.

Comment: if image is 4D then you have to convert into 3D ,their is no other option in deeplearning. It accept image only in 3D format ,use of np.reshape function convert into 3D format

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the fact is that the 4th dimension contains valuable information for my model.